# how to use a chrome profile with robot framework test

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I tried a lot of things and none of them worked. Here is my code in Robot Framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     String

Suite Teardown  Run Keyword    tear_down_actions

*** Keywords ***
tear_down_actions
    Close All Browsers
    

*** Variables ***
${browser}      chrome
${testURL}      https://www.google.com
${chrome_options}   add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1")


*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Open Browser   ${testURL}     ${browser}     ${chrome_options}
    Go To    chrome://version
```

Everytime I run this, a new profile directory is created under AppData\Local\Temp\scoped...\Default

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I tried add_argument with --incognito and it works. meaning "add_argument" is the correct use.

Answer (score 0):

I found some information that can be a good starting point

## Other people implementation

Here is a GIST by use Tset-Noitamotua [_Create_Webdriver.md](https://gist.github.com/Tset-Noitamotua/ab94b2e1b7ce3642f21429a3f4d89bb7) it use Selenium2Library so it is outdated.

## From the robot-framework SeleniumLibrary documentation

You can take a look at seleniumlibrary with the keyword [`Create webdriver`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Create%20Webdriver)

> I use it but personally, I found it difficult to use.

## My personal approach

I will create something in python and import it as a library on robot framework. The reason is that I want to abstract complexity and instead have just a few keywords to `load profiles` and `save profiles`.

Still working on it, but I created something in python + selenium + webdriver-manager (you can always create things in python and then import them to the robot framework).

### Pre-requisites

1. selenium
2. [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

### structure

To work, first, you need to create a directory at the same level of main.py called "browser_profiles", you need to create two more directories  "chrome" and "firefox" inside of each one you need to add the files from each profile.

### Code

> I'm thinking to make the webdriver_custome_profile.py a library and import it into the robot framework, initial test succeed but there is a lot of way to improvement.
> main.py

```py
from webdriver_custom_profile import create_webdrive
import os


browser_profiles = os.path.curdir.join(["browser_profiles"])
chrome_profile = os.path.join(browser_profiles+"/chrome")
firefox_profile = os.path.join(browser_profiles+"/firefox")

create_webdrive(browser="firefox", profile_dir=firefox_profile)
```

webdriver_custome_profile.py

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService


def create_webdrive(browser: str, profile_dir: str):
    """Create the driver following specific conditions

        Descriptions: The first version is not including the desired capabilities
        only focus in create a new webdrive following a profile specification
    """
    if browser.lower() == "chrome":
        chrome_service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        drive = _init_chrome(service=chrome_service ,user_data_dir=profile_dir)

    elif browser.lower() == "firefox":
        firefox_service = FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install())
        drive = _init_firefox(service=firefox_service, user_data_dir=profile_dir)

    return drive


def _init_chrome(service, user_data_dir: str, profile: str = "Profile 1"):
    """Create the drive following a chrome profile"""
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    if user_data_dir:
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={profile}")
        drive = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    return drive


def _init_firefox(service, user_data_dir: str):
    """Create the drive Following a firefox profile"""
    firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
    if user_data_dir:
        firefox_options.add_argument("-profile")
        firefox_options.add_argument(user_data_dir)
        drive = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=firefox_options)
    return drive
```

#### Where to find the profiles

here is an answer to that question https://superuser.com/questions/329112/where-are-the-user-profile-directories-of-google-chrome-located-in