# What is the default browser mode that robot framework runs in?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, robotframework

I am using chrome web driver and not specifying headless/incognito in the scripts. I am trying to add an extension called 'Windows accounts' so that it can remember the credentials used to log in. When I open the browser not through RIDE and add the extension to the browser settings it works fine but when I run through RIDE it does not show the extension that we had just added.

For example,

Open Browser  Chrome
Go To         [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

I see the browser open (does that mean it is not headless?) and I also don't see the incognito enabled in the browser. I assume that it opens the regular window with a fresh session.

Edit: I have learned that we can make our test remember the chrome profile so I have decided to use the 'Default' profile for now.

This is the code I have found here [Cannot open existing chrome profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226102/robot-framework-cannot-open-chrome-from-existing-chrome-profile)

Open Chrome Using Create WebDriver Keyword
[Tags]    test

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --allow-running-insecure-content
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --disable-web-security
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --user-data-dir\=/Users/myUserName/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
Go To    https://stackoverflow.com
```

Error:
Open Chrome Using Create WebDriver Keyword                            ....
DevTools listening on ******/devtools/browser/bda02058-c2f3-444b-89ca-8648f06b55cd
Open Chrome Using Create WebDriver Keyword                            | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

The browser opens with the Default profile and then test fails with the above error.
I am pretty sure I have not added the right code and that is because i don't understand it properly. I have looked on few pages and found java/python code and this was the only robotframework code I could find.
Please let me know how can this be fixed, thanks in advance.

Comment: When you open a browser, it creates a new empty profile. You can specify a different profile, these questions might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143603/how-to-use-a-chrome-profile-with-robot-framework-test and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I have looked at those pages and found the above code (edited the description)